# How to spread points evenly across an rmax

Tags: python, math

I have an rmax radius of a circle.

- rmax = 3.4 mm
- points = 150

How can I evenly distribute these points between 0 and rmax?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Show what you have tried so far (code) in a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Do these similar question solve your problem? [Uniform distribution over disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927347/uniform-distribution-over-disk); [Simulate a uniform distribution on a disc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120527/simulate-a-uniform-distribution-on-a-disc)

Comment: What do you call "evenly". Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your question is how to distribute *points* amount of points evenly between 0 and *rmax*. If that is indeed the case, you could use *numpy.linspace*, passing in the start value (*0*), the end value (*rmax*) and how many points there should be along the distribution (*points*):

```
import numpy as np
rmax = 3.4
points = 150
distribution = np.linspace(0, rmax, points)
```

Comment: so i need to distribute the points in 2D rather than 1D. Thats why linspace doesn't work. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Could you please specify your issue further? Do you need the points distributed in a 2D array?